# Create Silverlight Control that can be used as the layout root

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I create a control in silverlight that can be used as the layout root, but still have a "Template" property so I can wrap the users content inside another control using a style?

My current implementation is close, it takes the content that the user places in the control and wraps it but the user has to put a grid or panel in if there is multiple controls for the content.

--Update --
This is the code I'm using that will not work as the rootlayout for multiple children unless the user puts a grid around their content.  If I inherit from Grid or Panel I get an error about the DefaultStyleKey property not being available.

```
public class BusyControl :ContentControl
{
    public BusyControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(BusyControl);
    }
}

<Style TargetType="local:BusyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>                
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:BusyControl">
                <telerik:RadBusyIndicator DisplayAfter="0:0:0.5" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" BusyContent="{Binding BusyMessage}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is how I want the user to be able to use my new control with out having to wrap their content in a panel or grid.

```
<cdc:BusyControl x:Name="BusyControl">
        <some:Control x:Name="Control1" />
        <some:Control x:Name="Control2" />
    </cdc:BusyControl>
```

Comment: How would you have `BusyControl` choose to layout the content controls?  Like a StackPanel?

Comment: Yes, like a stackpanel would be fine

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that what you want is to derive your control from an `ItemsControl` not a `ContentControl`.  In any `ControlTemplate` that you use you can place the controls using an `ItemsPresenter` instead of the `ContentPresenter` you would have used in a `ContentControl`.

Comment: Sounds like this is what I want, but how do I get the users content inside of the ItemsPresenter there isnt a "Content" property that I can bind to. <ItemsPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ???

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want multiple controls, i.e. children, as content then you have to use some sort of panel, which is the base class for the .Children property.

Not sure if this is applicable to your situation.  I had trouble grasping exactly what's going on in your question.  Maybe you can make a custom user control that inherits from ContentControl.  As you may or may not know, custom user controls need a default style key.  With a custom user control you need to define a template in the default style.  Now the template can have a ContentControl somewhere inside of it and its content property should be template binding to the contentcontrol.content property.  Or you can override the OnContentChanged function and do whatever you want in that override function (like put a single object in the control by itself... or for multiple objects create a new grid/panel and then set the objects as the grid/panels children *for the user* and then do what ever it is you are doing with the grid/panel.  You would have to set/bind the content property on your new control.  Make sense?

I don't know about your error with the default style key, and i don't have any telerik controls, but couldn't you just inherit from your telerik busy indicator?  Would something like this work for you, (or put you on the right track).

```
protected override void OnContentChanged( object oldContent, object newContent )
    {
        //I dont know how you are assigning content, 
        //but i would say if it's IEnumerable and count is > 1 it should use your panel
        var newMultiContent = newContent as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
        if ( newMultiContent!=null && newMultiContent.Cast<object>().Count()>1)
        {
            var myNewContentContainer = new StackPanel();//or grid or whatever
            myNewContentContainer.Children.Clear();
            //add children
            foreach (var item in newMultiContent.OfType<UIElement>())
                myNewContentContainer.Children.Add(item);
            //instead of the old content that wasn't what you wanted, use the new content container
            base.OnContentChanged( oldContent, myNewContentContainer );
            //or maybe try this and call the base method at the beginning...
            Content = myNewContentContaint
        }
        else
            base.OnContentChanged( oldContent, newContent );
    }
```

Comment: I updated my original post with some code so you can see what I'm trying to do

Comment: The RadBusyIndicator doesn't support mutiple children for content.  I'll give your OnContentChagned a try

Comment: I updated mine too.  You cant have content equal multiple objects... content can only be one object, so if you look up at OnContentChanged, you can see how i took the multiple objects and put it in 1 stack panel, and passed the stack panel to the base method.  I don't know if using the base method will set it to the new stack panel, but if that doesnt work you can just call the base method first, then instead of calling the base method, just re-set the content to the stack panel.

Comment: Panel doesn't have an OnContentChanged and if inherit from RadBusyIndicator I get a content set more than once error

Comment: Did you try to override it inheriting from content control (not RadBusyIndicator)?  Anthony has a good point, a more fit solution might be to try ItemsControl, since you have multiple items you want for content.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your control inherit from Panel if you want it to be able to have multiple children. You will have to handle laying out the panel's child controls if you do this. See this [MSDN article on creating custom panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903936%28VS.95%29.aspx).

You can then specify your Template and stick the user content into the template.